# Let $G$ be a group and show that $|G:Z(G)|$ cannot be prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and show that $|G:Z(G)|$ cannot be prime where $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$ and $|G:Z(G)|$ is the index of $Z(G)$ in $G$.

This was in a test that I had recently but I was not able to get it despite trying many things. I got as far as $|G:Z(G)| =  \frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}$ = $|G/Z(G)|$. But I was not able to show the result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian. In fact, if $G/Z(G) = \langle g Z(G) \rangle$, then elements of $G$ are of the form $g^{i} z$, for some integer $i$ and $z \in Z(G)$, so it is not difficult to see that they commute pairwise.

Comment: But is $G/Z(G)$ always cyclic?

Comment: A group of prime order is always cyclic.

Comment: @continental: if it were, then all the groups would be abelian.

Comment: How does the fact that $G$ is abelian show that $|G/Z(G)|$ is not prime?

Comment: $G$ abelian $\iff$ $G = Z(G)$.

Comment: Ah I see thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, and thank *you*!