# If $|G/Z(G)|= p$ for a prime $p$, Can we have $|Z(G)|=p^2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I came across this theorem in many of algebra books.

If $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, then $G$ is abelian.

I tried to apply it when $G=p^3$ and $Z(G)=p^2$. What I got is $|G/Z(G)|=p$ so is cyclic. Therefore, $G$ is abelian according to the theorem which yields $G=Z(G)$ contradiction!
So I thought either theorem doesn't apply here or we cannot have the centre of degree $p^2$. Am I right? If so, Which one is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: You have just shown that $|G|=p^3$ and $|Z(G)|=p^2$ is impossible, correct.

Comment: This is correct. More generally, it is impossible for $G/Z(G)$ to have prime order, regardless of whether $G$ has prime power order or not.

Comment: [This duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550304/let-g-be-a-group-and-show-that-gzg-cannot-be-prime) is the better one, for the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every group of order $p$ is cyclic. Therefore, by the theorem you cited, $G/Z(G)$ cannot be of order $p$. Hence, $|G|=p^{3}$ and $|Z(G)|=p^{2}$ is impossible.

Comment: Noncyclic $p$-groups certainly do exist, consider e.g. $C_p\times C_p$. There even exist nonabelian ones.

Comment: I meant to write "of order $p$", of course.